# Upper bound Gaussian mass of shifted subset $\gamma(A + s)$.

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $A$ be a "nice" subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (compact, convex, symmetric). Let $\gamma(A) = \int_A\exp(-\pi \lVert x\rVert^2)dx $.
I'm interested in a "nice" upper-bound on $\gamma(A + y)$, where $y$ is some vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For example, there is a lower bound $\gamma(A + y) \geq \gamma(A) \exp(-\pi \lVert y\rVert^2)$ which is "nice" (see [lemma 3.3 of this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7979.pdf)).
Following the same argument as in that linked paper, you can get that

$$\gamma(A + y) = \exp(-\pi \lVert y\rVert^2)\int_{A}\exp(-\pi \lVert x\rVert^2)\cosh(\langle x, y\rangle)\mathrm{d}x.$$
The "nice" proof then finishes by lower-bounding $\cosh(x)\geq 1$.
Such a bound is clearly not available in my situation.